# Perl && do { last; };

Tags: perl, for-loop

In my book it uses something like this:

```
for($ARGV[0])
{
Expression && do { print "..."; last; };
...
}
```

Isn't the `for`-loop incomplete? Also, what's the point of the `do`, couldn't it just be `{ ... }`, or does the `do` have some importance here?

Comment: They "`for`" and "`foreach`" keywords are completely equivalent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two forms of `for` statement in Perl.  The one you're seeing here is often written as `foreach`, but `for` and `foreach` are synonyms.  It normally iterates over a list, setting `$_` to each element.  In this case, the "list" is a single value, so it has the effect of setting `$_` to `$ARGV[0]` for the body of the loop.

The `do` is needed to make the block `{ ... }` into an expression, so it can be an operand of the `&&` operator.  (See what happens if you omit the word `do`.)

(And you were missing a semicolon; I've edited the question to fix that.)

Comment: My question is "why?" I think you could rewrite this just fine as `$_=$ARGV[0]; if (Expression) { print "..."; last }` and it might make more sense.

Comment: It's just stylistic. One advantage is that the expression you're testing is really obviously the first thing on the line, a bit like a case statement in C. I often use it with regexps: /foo=(\w+)/ && do {$store{foo} = process_foo($1)};